# uniformly discrete in one metric but not in the other giving the same topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is it possible to define two metrics on $X$ giving the same topologies such that there exists a nonempty subset of $X$ which is uniformly discrete in one but not in the other?

Comment: You are aware that the two metrics in hartkp's answer give the same topology on the set $X=\{2^{-n}:n\in\omega\}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sequence $\{2^{-n}:n\in\omega\}$ is not uniformly discrete with respect to the metric it inherits from the real line, but it is uniformly discrete with respect to the discrete metric.